# Phonegap simple editing

Tags: objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am currently about to start on a project in PhoneGap / Cordova.

In the application I would like to take a photo, with the getPicture function, and after this do a very simple photo editing.

The editing consist of the simple thing to add two points (circles, dots, whatever) to the picture, and then save it, and use for upload.

I can't seem to find any plugins offering this function, so what I seem to need is some native code, that I can implement as a plugin by myself.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Any help, pointing me in the right direction will make me happy.
Thank you,

Jens

Comment: the task is not easy for PhoneGap, man.

Comment: I know that. :)
That is why I am asking for suggestions how to do it with native code, and then implement it as a plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is html5 canvas. 
I have experienced in editing the image on the webcam with phonegap.
However, the requirement of you seems to be easier. You can take a photo with getPicture api at first. Then do what you want on canvas.